# Power series approximation for any function such as $-e^{x^{2}}$ in some easily-accessed open-source software?

Tags: software, education

My comrades repeatedly encourages monotonous problems where the issue is the same: chain-rule and some basic arithmetic. Is there some computational way to derive power series approximations? Suppose I plug in some function such as $e^{x^{2}+x+ln(x)+x^{777}}$, $e^{x^2}$ or $x^{777}-ln(x)+e^{2x+1}$, some command such as `Series(e^{x^{2}})` to get you the series? It would be useful to see graphically how things change, which would help me to learn things graphically.

Comment: FWIW if open-sourceness is not a requirement, I think Mathematica (or Wolfram Alpha) is currently the most user-friendly tool for this sort of thing.

Comment: Isn't this just your question [Is there any open-source or easy-to-access software that can...](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/1088/149) with a different example problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a few options:

- Sage: Documentation for power series is [here](http://www.sagemath.org/doc/constructions/calculus.html). (Scroll down until you reach "Power series.") Documentation for plotting functions is [here](http://www.sagemath.org/doc/reference/sage/plot/plot3d/plot3d.html).

  ```
  sage: var('x')
  x
  sage: f = exp(x^2 + x + log(x) + x^777)
  sage: f.taylor(x, 0, 3)                
  3/2*x^3 + x^2 + x
  ```
- [SymPy](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/mpmath/calculus/approximation.html) (Right on that page, first heading) + [Matplotlib](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/)
- [Maxima](http://www.ma.utexas.edu/maxima/maxima_29.html) (Search for "Taylor series" on that page.) + [Gnuplot](http://www.gnuplot.info/) (or Matplotlib, or another plotting package you prefer)

For any of the software packages listed in your earlier question on [open-source math software packages](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/1088/is-there-any-open-source-or-easy-to-access-software-that-can-simplify-algebraic), you can probably search around and find the appropriate command.

Comment: SymPy, Matplotlib and Maxima are all built into Sage, so you only need to install one package if you want to try them all out.